# Not able to send larger byte arrays in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, arrays

I have a WCF service and i am sending the following datacontract

```
[DataContract]
public class Sample
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] ByteList { get; set; }
}
```

But as the byte array size increases the client is not accepting the data. Other messages are successfully received by them. I tried increasing the size in .config. I also tried sending the object after serializing using DataContractSerializer but nothing is working for me. I know its some mistake in my side but i cant figure it out. Please let me know your comments

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="tcpbinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxConnections="10"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="true" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

Comment: What is the exact exception you're seeing (including any inner exceptions)?

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions. Its just i am not receiving the message. Server is sending the message but it is not received in the callback event though. But i am receiving other messages concurrently. Also if the size of the byte array is smaller i am getting the message.

Comment: Strange... Try turning on Tracing on the client and take a look at the trace (and in particular look for any exceptions that may be getting swallowed). See e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx

Comment: Have you added the same settings on the client side as well?

Comment: Yes rajesh . client have the same settings as well.. But i had no idea where am i going wrong..:-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of WCF settings...

How large can the array be before you start losing messages (i.e. what is the largest array you can transfer successfully)?

From my experience, the setting relating to arrays is **maxArrayLength** (not maxItemsInObjectGraph, which deals with hierarchical data). Make sure this setting (and also **maxReceivedMessageSize**) is larger than any ByteList length in both server **and** client configurations.

WCF hides its error messages well, but you can set up tracing to find them. On the *server*, add this under the **configuration** node in the web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="messages"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Warning, Critical, Error, Verbose"
            propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="sdt"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData= "c:\logs\service.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging
         logEntireMessage="true"
         logMalformedMessages="true"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
         maxMessagesToLog="3000000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Note**

- You must manually create the log files folder (here: c:\logs) on the server first.
- With these settings, the log files (service.svclog in particular) grow huge very fast. Only turn on this kind of logging when you really need it.

**References**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

*The latter also shows you how to open and read the log files. You should see at least one error message in service.svclog after you make a service call that doesn't return a message.*

Comment: Thanks sphinxxx for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048000" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

to your config.

if that doesn't resolve the problem then add

```
<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
```

too like below

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior name="myNetTcpBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myNetTcpEndPointBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But would it work since i am using nettcpbinding and httpGetEnabled should be "false". And where shall i add <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048000" executionTimeout="3600" />

Comment: Anywhere within <system.web> tag

Comment: also the main thing is adding <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>, "httpGetEnabled = true" in my code is just an example.

Comment: did you try adding <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>